# What is the soundtrack that plays in Tokyo Ghoul root A, episode 9?

Tags: music, tokyo-ghoul

What is the soundtrack that plays at *19:45 to 22:22* of *Tokyo Ghoul root A* Episode 9?

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the fight scene of Kaneki and Amon the song's name is **Glassy Sky**  from Donna Burke : [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vvvvcpwFw5o)

Comment: i recommand adding a youtube link to your answer

Comment: OP does this answer your question. If so please accept and close. If not please leave feedback as to why

Answer (score 0):

It took me forever to find it but it’s called Das zweite Kapitel here is the link to make things easier https://youtu.be/ZRFSbWRyjAw